# How to get the id of the element by using hover droppable function

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

How to get the ID of the element by hover Droppable function?

[image]

I want to get the drag-n-drop id hover on indent icon. Can anybody help me solve this?

```js
$("ul li").droppable({

 over: function(event, ui) {

  var drag_id = ui.draggable.attr('id');

  $("#"+drag_id).css({
   "background":"#fff","border-top":"1px solid #333","border-bottom":"1px solid #333"
  });
 },
 drop: function(event, ui) {

  var drag_id = ui.draggable.attr('id');
  var target_id = event.target.id;  
  
  $("#"+drag_id).css({
   "background":"#fff","border-top":"1px solid #333","border-bottom":"1px solid #333"
  });
  setInterval(function(){
   $("#"+drag_id).css({
    "border-top":"","border-bottom":""
   });
  }, 2000);
  var from_pos = drag_id;
  var to_pos = target_id;
  changepositions(from_pos,to_pos);
  // existing stuff 
 }
});
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXzAG.png you able to see the image in the link

Comment: Please share us the code you have tries so far.

Comment: Sibeesh i have share the javascript code can you please look in to

Comment: I am poor in English could u please explain "_I want to get the drag-n-drop id hover on indent icon_"?

Comment: You can able to see the id = 6 and id = 5 one move the 6th id element to 5th id element want to get the both ids

Comment: Sorry i missed that , you want id of 6 when it's hovering (but not dropped) above 5 right?

Comment: yes want to get both item id on hover on icon near by id 5,

Comment: now i can able to get drag id var drag_id = ui.draggable.attr('id');

Comment: only on hover on icon near by id 5 want to get that id too

Comment: thanks Sibeesh
keep in touch 9688117336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in [over](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over)  it has an `event` parameter from that you can get it's `target` then it `id` like this

```
    over: function(event, ui) {

      var drop_id = event.target.id; //<-- 5
      alert(drop_id);

      var drag_id = ui.draggable.attr('id');
      alert(drop_id);                //<-- 6

      //other stuff
    },
```

EDIT : Added by OP

thanks i used this one

```
$(".indent").droppable({

        drop: function(event, ui) {

            console.log($(this), ui.draggable);

            $(this).append(ui.draggable);

            var target_id = event.target.id; //<--5
            alert(target_id);

            var drag_id = ui.draggable.attr('id');
            alert(drop_id);                //<-- 6

        },
        hoverClass: 'drop-area',
        greedy: true,
        tolerance: "pointer"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-activate). It do describe about different events which are fired while dragging and dropping an element using jquery-ui. The event `activate` in which `event` and `ui` are available as parameters may be helpful for you. The ui parameter wil contain `handler` element from which you can get the id of dragged element using `attr` method of jquery.